# why this FD make 3NF?

Tags: database-design, normalization

Question like this:

Consider the relation scheme ABCDEF satisfying the following functional dependencies:

BC --> ADEF

CD --> B

E --> D

BC is a key and designated as primary. Explain why the relation is in 3NF.

It seems not a 3NF to me, because E-->D is a transitive dependency, but the question asked like this it must to be a 3NF ? So how do I explain it's a 3NF?

Comment: `CD` and `CE` seem like candidate keys as well.

Comment: Thank you ! I think you are right. If I use CD as key, then E-->D won't consider as transitive dependency.

Comment: Yes. But it's not a matter what you choose for keys. You have to show which key combinations are candidate keys. And then clearly (as you notice) E->D is not transitive dependency so it doesn't ruin 3NF.